# Probability of a coin tossed using Markov Chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

A coin is tossed repeatedly until two successive heads appear.I have to find the mean number of tossed required using a Markov Chain and it's transition matrix.

Here's my attempt:

Let X be the random variable that represents the number of tossed required.So we need to find E(X), where E is the mean.

Otherwise,let $\ X_n$ be the cumulative number of successive heads.The state space is o,1,2 and the transition probability matrix is$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
        1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and then I don't know how to continue, I mean how to relate both things
 **:(**

Comment: Did you mean to put a 1 in the last row of your matrix?

Comment: @AndrewGray yes, it's 1 instead of 2. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$E_0 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}E_0 + \frac{1}{2}E_1$

$E_1 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}E_0 + \frac{1}{2}E_2$

$E_2 = 0$

This simplifies to $E_0 = 6$, which tells you the expected number of flips at the start of the game. We also have $E_1 = 4$ (the expected number of steps when you have already flipped a head).

If you want to use the Markov chain instead:

$N = (I - Q)^{-1} = 
        \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  
        \end{bmatrix} 
- 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1/2 & 1/2  \\
        1/2 & 0 
        \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}
= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1/2 & -1/2  \\
        -1/2 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 2  \\
        2 & 2
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Then the expected number of steps for each transient state is:

$t = N1 =   
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 2  \\
        2 & 2
        \end{bmatrix} 
\cdot   
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 
        \end{bmatrix} 
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        6 \\
        4 
        \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I also have to find the mean time to reach state 2 starting from state 0 by invoking first step analysis, and the answer is the same as $ \ E_0$=6. Do you think my  answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, $E_0$ is the expected number of steps needed to reach state $2$ from $0$. State $2$ is considered a final "absorbing" state.